# Sogou Custom Keyboard not firing keyboardWillShow

Tags: ios, keyboard-events

An app we made utilizes `keyboardWillShow` notifications from `NSNotificationCenter`

Everything was working as expected until we tried to use the app with a device that had the [Sogou](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sou-gou-shu-ru-fa-sogou-keyboard/id917670924?mt=8) custom keyboard installed. When this keyboard is used (which oddly enough it doesn't seem to always come up -- for instance secure text entries ignore the Sogou keyboard) the keyboardWillShow notification is not firing.

Does anyone know of this issue or how to disable the use of custom keyboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to get this to work was to disable all custom keyboards using the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:(NSString *)extensionPointIdentifier {
    if ([extensionPointIdentifier isEqualToString: UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```